# Moving a refrigerator

Tags: kitchens, ice-maker

First question, I am moving and have friends helping. How do they disconnect the ice maker from the water line?  Are there specifics they need to follow?

Second question, I am moving a frig. It will be placed in the garage of the new house without a water line. What do I do to the ice maker connection so it doesn't grow mold. It will be used but without water.

Comment: Side point: When moving the refrigerator, always keep it as vertical as you can. Sometimes they don't work after being transported horizontally.

Comment: Along that line, if it has to be tipped significantly, let it rest for a couple of hours before plugging it in.  I'm curious how you are going to use an ice maker without water, though.

Comment: I will not be using it. The frig will be in a garage and the ice maker will not be used.

Comment: The caution is to keep the fridge upright so the oil in the compressor stays in the compressor, if the fridge has to be laid down it needs to be upright for 8-24 hours prior to being plugged in or the compressor may be ruined when plugged in two soon. As far as the ice maker I usually plug the line if not being used , if you want to use it in the future a hydrogen peroxide or bleach flush would be a good idea after sitting but there is not much that will clean the loop out completely while not in use.